# Поиск уникальных значений в определенном интервале символов

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть табличка, из которой мне охота сгруппировать данные по полю number:

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `number`,$db); // работает
```

Можно ли сделать такую же группировку по number, но не по всему number, а с 2го по 5й символ (3 символа)? т.е.: из 8388608, 8387608, 8388609 - должен найти 2 записи

p.s. в моем примере получается перебирают 3 записи (реально их несколько тысяч) , и у них с 2го по 5й символ: 886, 876, 886. далее группируем их, получаем 886, 876. был бы раз услышать, что то в роде:

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `substr(number,2,3)`,$db);
```

Comment: Если вам нужно получить все записи и сгруппировать в определённом-хитро-закрученном порядке, а не по возрастающей/убывающей, попробуйте группировать уже полученный результат скриптом.

Comment: а можно поподробнее про то какую группировку вы хотите - я из вашего примера не совсем понял(

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
table:

numbers
--id
--num

sql:

SELECT SUBSTRING( num, 1, 3 ) , COUNT( * ) 
FROM numbers
GROUP BY SUBSTRING( num, 1, 3 ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30

result(например):

substring(num,1,3) | count(*)
123                | 2
838                | 3
```

- уходите от нативного mysql_*. (используйте например PDO, mysqli, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте WHERE:

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `number` WHERE `number` > чего то AND WHERE `number` < чего то,$db);
```

Это как вариант.

Comment: это отсеет часть записей, но смысл то в этом? мне то нужно сгруппировать